# Jewish Archaeology

Tags: history, product-recommendation, books-generally, archaeology

I'm looking for a good read which discusses archaeology and the Tanach, Chazal, etc. Could anyone point me to some resources? I would prefer that the book be in English, and have pictures throughout.

It would be best if the book was from a reliable Jewish source, not a scholarly one, so that there are minimal conflictions between the contents and traditional Jewish belief.

Comment: Read the distinguished [William F. Albright](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_F._Albright)'s numerous books.

Comment: @Oliver Not a Jewish source.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40702/8775

Comment: @ezra Indeed he was not Jewish but was recognized by many Jewish scholars as a bona fide authority in the field.

Comment: Not English, but [this](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=676) book is relevant. It has an nontraditional dating in a lot of cases, and I can't say how strong the argument is, but it's interesting to read their interpretation (e.g. they date the Amarna letters to Jeremiah's time, whereas the traditional date is around Joshua's)

Comment: They're more from a scholarly viewpoint(but Hershel Shanks is Jewish), but the Bookstore @the Biblical Archaeology Society has some great reads: http://store.bib-arch.org/Books/products/31/2/0     Ancient Israel, From Abraham to the Roman Destruction of the Temple is one of my favorites - just tons of info and great pictures in one reasonably priced book.  Their 5 volume Encyclopedia of Archaeological Excavations of the Holy Land is more pricey, but it IS a reference work.

Comment: Also, Yigael Yadin's early books on Hazor, Masada, and Bar Kochba are great.  And the Mazar family's(Benjamin, Amihai, Eilat)books on their excavations are also very good.

Answer (score 4):

Not a book but otherwise fits exactly what you ask: [R Amnon Bazak](https://www.korenpub.com/maggid_en_usd/rabbi-amnon-bazak?limit=all) has a [series of written shiurim on Tanakh and Archaeology](http://etzion.org.il/en/topics/fundamental-issues-study-tanakh?combine=&page=1) in English, see  shiurim 6a to 6i.

He offers a fairly comprehensive review of the archaeological record in regard to Tanakh. He states there is no archaeological evidence that contradicts the Torah - actually he writes there are many findings that do conform to the biblical narratives from the times of the forefathers and indicate that these narratives were indeed written with a profound familiarity with the period. He notes the same same regarding the era of enslavement and subsequent exodus from Egypt.

<sup>(from p. 102-103 in [Reason to believe](http://etzion.org.il/en/topics/fundamental-issues-study-tanakh?combine=&page=1) by R Chaim Jachter)</sup>

---

As a followup, I have now read [Excavating the Bible: New Archaeological Evidence for the Historical Reliability of Scripture](http://a.co/d/ivfcIFV) by Yitzhak Meitlis. The author is a religious Jew (and has a personal approbation from R Pinchas Stolper). The book focuses on retracing the Tanakh through excavations of the Judean Hills and Jerusalem. I found it enjoyable to read and it connects nicely the biblical text with the reality of excavations.

From amazon

> He leads the reader on a lively exploration of the ancient cities of
>   the Judean Hills, and the birth of an Israelite nation and the
>   people’s challenge to remaining a people committed to God as described
>   in the Prophets and later Writings. The journey culminates in
>   Jerusalem, where the reader watches the rise and fall of one
>   civilization after another; views the audacious exploits that
>   delivered the city into the hands of David; pictures its glory at the
>   height of its power; and watches in horror as it meets its fiery end.

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi Michael Shelomo Bar-on actually wrote a book on this topic called [*Oral Torah from Sinai:The case for the authenticity of the Oral Torah*](https://www.amazon.ca/Oral-Torah-Sinai-Case-Authenticity/dp/0979261899) relating to this topic. You can also see his works on [Acaedemia.edu](https://independent.academia.edu/MichaelBarRon6). Where he specializes in the topic of Archaeology and Tanach.

Additionally [here](http://www.torathmoshe.com/) is his personal website.

Hope this is helpful