# Archaeological findings of events in the Torah or Neviim Rishonim

Tags: archaeology

I am looking for archaeological findings that support what is written in the Torah or Neviim Rishonim. I am looking for non-sensational findings that are agreed upon by the general scientific community.Also, I am not necessarily looking for confirmation of miracles but just a confirmation of any the events, people or objects mentioned.

Comment: I've voted to close as too broad.

Comment: You might find the [Cyrus Cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrus_Cylinder) of particular interest, as well as [Sennacherib's Annals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sennacherib%27s_Annals).

Comment: You are aware that the archeological findings clearly contradict the Torah, yes?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_artifacts_in_biblical_archaeology

Comment: @nbubis Not always

Comment: [This book](http://a.co/6OvKvpw) came highly recommended but I haven't read it yet

Comment: see also [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87121/11501) and my answer there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Biblical Archaeology Review has a list of [53 people](https://www.biblicalarchaeology.org/daily/people-cultures-in-the-bible/people-in-the-bible/50-people-in-the-bible-confirmed-archaeologically/) that archaeology has confirmed in the bible. All of these are things that are generally agreed upon by the scientific community (although just as with any community of people, there are always some outliers in every direction). It includes ketuvim too so it's a little broader than your question in that sense. The full article at BAR contains details on all of these. Here is the list:

## Egypt

1   Shishak (= Sheshonq I)  pharaoh 945–924 1 Kings 11:40, etc.

2   So (= Osorkon IV)   pharaoh 730–715 2 Kings 17:4

3   Tirhakah (= Taharqa)    pharaoh 690–664 2 Kings 19:9, etc

4   Necho II (= Neco II)    pharaoh 610–595 2 Chronicles 35:20, etc.

5   Hophra (= Apries)   pharaoh 589–570 Jeremiah 44:30

## Moab

6   Mesha   king    early to mid-ninth century  2 Kings 3:4–27

## Aram-Damascus

7   Hadadezer   king    early ninth century to 844/842  1 Kings 11:23, etc.

8   Ben-hadad, son of Hadadezer king    844/842 2 Kings 6:24, etc.

9   Hazael  king    844/842–c. 800  1 Kings 19:15, etc.

10  Ben-hadad, son of Hazael    king    early eighth century    2 Kings 13:3, etc.

11  Rezin   king    mid-eighth century to 732   2 Kings 15:37, etc.

## Northern Kingdom

12  Omri    king    884–873 1 Kings 16:16, etc.

13  Ahab    king    873–852 1 Kings 16:28, etc.

14  Jehu    king    842/841–815/814 1 Kings 19:16, etc.

15  Joash (= Jehoash)   king    805–790 2 Kings 13:9, etc.

16  Jeroboam II king    790–750/749 2 Kings 13:13, etc.

17  Menahem king    749–738 2 Kings 15:14, etc.

18  Pekah   king    750(?)–732/731  2 Kings 15:25, etc.

19  Hoshea  king    732/731–722 2 Kings 15:30, etc.

20  Sanballat “I”   governor of Samaria under Persian rule  c. mid-fifth century    Nehemiah 2:10, etc.

## Southern Kingdom

21  David   king    c. 1010–970 1 Samuel 16:13, etc.

22  Uzziah (= Azariah)  king    788/787–736/735 2 Kings 14:21, etc.

23  Ahaz (= Jehoahaz)   king    742/741–726 2 Kings 15:38, etc.

24  Hezekiah    king    726–697/696 2 Kings 16:20, etc.

25  Manasseh    king    697/696–642/641 2 Kings 20:21, etc.

26  Hilkiah high priest during Josiah’s reign   within 640/639–609  2 Kings 22:4, etc.

27  Shaphan scribe during Josiah’s reign    within 640/639–609  2 Kings 22:3, etc.

28  Azariah high priest during Josiah’s reign   within 640/639–609  1 Chronicles 5:39, etc.

29  Gemariah    official during Jehoiakim’s reign   within 609–598  Jeremiah 36:10, etc.

30  Jehoiachin (= Jeconiah = Coniah)    king    598–597 2 Kings 24:6, etc.

31  Shelemiah   father of Jehucal the royal official    late seventh century    Jeremiah 37:3, etc.

32  Jehucal (= Jucal)   official during Zedekiah’s reign    within 597–586  Jeremiah 37:3, etc.

33  Pashhur father of Gedaliah the royal official   late seventh century    Jeremiah 38:1

34  Gedaliah    official during Zedekiah’s reign    within 597–586  Jeremiah 38:1

## Assyria

35  Tiglath-pileser III (= Pul) king    744–727 2 Kings 15:19, etc.

36  Shalmaneser V   king    726–722 2 Kings 17:3, etc.

37  Sargon II   king    721–705 Isaiah 20:1

38  Sennacherib king    704–681 2 Kings 18:13, etc.

39  Adrammelech (= Ardamullissu = Arad-mullissu)    son and assassin of Sennacherib early seventh century   2 Kings 19:37, etc.

40  Esarhaddon  king    680–669 2 Kings 19:37, etc.

## Babylon

41  Merodach-baladan II king    721–710 and 703 2 Kings 20:12, etc.

42  Nebuchadnezzar II   king    604–562 2 Kings 24:1, etc.

43  Nebo-sarsekim   official of Nebuchadnezzar II   early sixth century Jeremiah 39:3

44  Nergal-sharezer officer of Nebuchadnezzar II    early sixth century Jeremiah 39:3

45  Nebuzaradan a chief officer of Nebuchadnezzar II    early sixth century 2 Kings 25:8, etc. & Jeremiah 39:9, etc.

46  Evil-merodach (= Awel Marduk = Amel Marduk) king    561–560 2 Kings 25:27, etc.

47  Belshazzar  son and co-regent of Nabonidus  c. 543?–540 Daniel 5:1, etc.

## Persia

48  Cyrus II (= Cyrus the Great)    king    559–530 2 Chronicles 36:22, etc.

49  Darius I (= Darius the Great)   king    520–486 Ezra 4:5, etc.

50  Tattenai    provincial governor of Trans-Euphrates  late sixth to early fifth century   Ezra 5:3, etc.

51  Xerxes I (= Ahasuerus)  king    486–465 Esther 1:1, etc.

52  Artaxerxes I Longimanus king    465-425/424 Ezra 4:7, etc.

53  Darius II Nothus    king    425/424-405/404 Nehemiah 12:22

Comment: There's also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baruch_ben_Neriah#Historicity though that's a bit controversial.

Answer (score -1):

As a general rule, you find plenty archaeological evidence in the Bible for events which were written down by authors that lived near the time of the events, though the evidence sometimes shows that the the biblical authors "fixed" the historical story to match their ideology. As the date of authorship becomes farther away from the date in which the events described happened, evidence becomes scarce, and the evidence found at times contradicts the story entirely.

Here are some key examples:

*The Exodus*

Whatever traditions the exodus story is based on, archaeological evidence shows that Egypt was in fact the ruler of Canaan during the 14th century BC, and that no mass changes to the population (600,000 men plus their families would have constituted around half the population of Egypt at that time) seem to have happened. Cities and nations mentioned by name in Exodus are known to have only existed many hundreds of years later, Camel's are known not to have brought to Egypt until many hundreds of years later, as well as many other issues. In short, here the archaeological evidence clearly dismisses the biblical story, and indeed, we're talking about some 700 years before the reign of Josiah.

*David and Solomon's Kingdom*

There is no real archaeological evidence for the large united kingdom of David and Solomon large kingdom described in the Bible, with a lack of large structures and inhabited sites that would be required in such a kingdom. The earliest evidence we have for David is from the [Tel Dan Stele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tel_Dan_Stele) which only mentioned the "House of David", not David himself. In short, at the very least, no real evidence.

*Kings of Israel*

The Omrides are mentioned in multiple archaeological findings, with the defeat of Joram son of Ahab mentioned in the [Mesha Stele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesha_Stele).

*Assyrian siege of Jerusalem*

The famous Assyrian clay prisms describe Sennacherib's siege on Jerusalem, and agree with most biblical details, other than the miracle described in the bible, where 185,000 of Sennacherib's troops perished overnight.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The request was for confirmation, not contradiction.

Comment: @user6591 - There three confirming examples in my answer. Do you want more, or do you just want a an answer that ignores the stuff that contradicts certain beliefs?

Comment: It's not what I want. It's what the OP wants. A request was made for proof to one side of an argument. The major thrust of this answer seems to be an attempt to prove the opposing view. It's not a matter of intellectual honesty or religious doctrine. It's a matter of answering with an appropriate answer.

Comment: Actually, I remember some articles that showed that the timeline that denies the tanach statements (such as Yehoshuah or the kingdoms of Dovid and Shlomo) were actually off because of the assumptions as to what period the items found actually should be assigned to. Thus, the assumption of a period *belonging* to the kingdoms of Dovid and Shloo were placed in an area were there were no indications. Indications of major populations and economic activity were assumed to be Cannanite and destructions caused by the entry of Bnai Yisrael were assumed to be either earlier or later.